# Requires working strangely / truffle / tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test, require

My contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract GuessAndWin is Ownable{
    string public hint; 
    string private word; //word to find
    mapping(address => uint) HasTried; // HasTried[0] => never play, HasTried[1] tried once
    address[] private log;
    address public winner;
    constructor(string memory _hint, string memory _word) {
        require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_hint)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_word)), "word and hint have to be different");
        hint = _hint;
        word = _word;
    }
    /*
        verify if the player has already tried once
        write in the mapping that this address tried
        then compare the try and the word
        if it match, send all contract's eth to msg.sender
        return true
        else return false
    */
    function proposeWord(string memory tmpString)external payable returns(bool){
        require(HasTried[msg.sender] < 1, "Sorry, you already got your chance");
        require(msg.value >= (1 ether - tx.gasprice), "Pay 1 eth to try");
        HasTried[msg.sender] += 1;
        log.push(msg.sender);
        if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tmpString)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(word))){
            (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: seePrize()}("");
            require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
            restart();
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

    /*
        Owner can change the word, but restart the mapping to be fair
    */
    function changeWord(string memory str, string memory hintStr)external onlyOwner{
        require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(str)) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked(hintStr)), "word and hint have to be different");
        hint = hintStr;
        word = str;
        restart();
    }
    /*
        restart the mapping;
    */
    function restart() internal {
        for(uint i; i < log.length; i++){
            HasTried[log[i]] = 0;
        }
        delete log;
    }

    /*
        winner = 0x00... means nobody find the word
    */
    function hasSomeoneWin()external view returns(bool){
        if(winner == 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000){
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }

    
    function seePrize()public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    receive()external payable{

    }

}
```

Tests :

```
const { contracts } = require('@openzeppelin/cli/lib/prompts/choices');
const { BN, ether, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
const { expect, assert } = require('chai');
const GuessAndWinContract = artifacts.require('GuessAndWin');
contract('GuessAndWin', function(accounts){
    const owner = accounts[0];
    const recipient = accounts[1];

    beforeEach(async function(){
        this.cInstance = await GuessAndWinContract.new('test test', 'test', {from:owner});
    });

    describe('#INITIALISATION', function(){
        it('verify if owner is msg.sender', async function(){
            const contractOwner = await this.cInstance.owner()
            expect(contractOwner).to.be.equal(owner);
        });
        it('should not accept to create a contract with hint == word', async function(){
            await expectRevert(this.cInstance.changeWord('test', 'test', {from:owner}), "word and hint have to be different");
        });
    });
    describe('#PROPOSE A WORD', function(){
        it('should return true when submiting the right word', async function(){
            const bool = await this.cInstance.proposeWord('test', {from:owner, value:(1*10**18)});
            expect(bool).to.be.ok;
        });
        it('should return false when submiting the right word', async function(){
            const bool = await this.cInstance.proposeWord('coucou', {from:owner, value:(1*10**18)});
            expect(bool).to.be.ok;
        });
        **it('should revert if user has already try', async function(){
            await this.cInstance.proposeWord('coucou', {from:owner, value:(1*10*18)});
            await expectRevert(this.cInstance.proposeWord('coucou', {from:owner, value:(1*10*18)}), "Sorry, you already got your chance");
        })**
    })
});
```

The last unit test (should revert if user already tried) failed with this message :

```
  1) Contract: GuessAndWin
       #PROPOSE A WORD
         should revert if user has already try:
     Transaction: 0x9f82fe74d488929e8a2d5c0df81c8ed783409687b9c98ccd43c7b0f5af79b5e8 exited with an error (status 0). Reason given: Pay 1 eth to try.
     Please check that the transaction:
     - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.
     - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.

  StatusError: Transaction: 0x9f82fe74d488929e8a2d5c0df81c8ed783409687b9c98ccd43c7b0f5af79b5e8 exited with an error (status 0). Reason given: Pay 1 eth to try.
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/testGuessAndWin.js:33:34)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

Do someone know why the test fail and why does the second require triggering before the first ?

Answer (score 0):

In the last test you have a typo in your sent value `1*10*18` instead of `1*10**18`